# How to get django_hitcount app working with Mezzanine blog

Tags: django, mezzanine

Been trying for several hours now.

I set up according to instructions but I can't get it to count hits on a blog post.

/blog/blog_post_detail.html

```
{% load .. .. .. hitcount_tags %}

.
.
.
.
{% block blog_post_detail_content %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()  {
       {% get_hit_count_javascript for blog_post %} 
    });
</script>

{% get_hit_count for blog_post %}
.
.
.
{% endblock %}
```

And in my urls.py I added:

```
url(r'^blog/ajax/hit/$', update_hit_count_ajax, name='hitcount_update_ajax'),
```

Looking at page source in browser the javascript does appear to run.

```
    $(document).ready(function()  {
       var csrf = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
$.post( '/blog/ajax/hit/',
{ csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf, hitcount_pk : '1' },
function(data, status) {
    if (data.status == 'error') {
        // do something for error?
    }
    },
'json'); 
    });
```

But it's not counting.  So I'm not quite sure why it doesn't count a page hit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  In Mezzanine you have to put custom url patterns above the

```
("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
```

pattern otherwise they will be ignored.